# What's the most efficient way to pass a parameter between classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, variables, parameters, tkinter

I am currently building a user based system, where I have a class for a login screen in pythons tkinter. Once the user information is correct it will initiate a class for the menu. I'm using an SQL database which python reads and checks user information with. I'm going to need the username of the user to be passed to the menu class so the class knows what information to display on that menu.

```
from tkinter import *

class Login:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.label = Label(self.master, text = "enter name")
        self.entry = Entry(self.master)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text = "submit", command = self.loadMenu)

        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2)

        self.name = self.entry.get()

    def loadMenu(self):
        self.menu = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.app = Menu(self.menu)


class Menu:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.label = Label(self.master, text = "dave")

        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    run = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the above example code, what method could be used to pass the variable 'self.name' to class menu so that it can be displayed in a label? I am trying not to use a global variable. Many Thanks.

Comment: `Menu(self.menu, self.name)`...!?

Comment: Note that you are masking tkinter's own `Menu` class.

Comment: @deceze that doesn't work

Comment: Did you change `Menu.__init__`'s method signature to match it?

Comment: Why "doesn't it work"?

Comment: Let's put it this way: you're already passing `self.menu` from `Login` to `Menu`... What's the issue with using the exact same technique to pass an additional value?!

Comment: I'm assigning the class to new window I've just created, it's not the same as passing a variable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that first bit, but you just need `self.app = Menu(self.menu, self.name)` and then `def __init__(self, master, name):` and `self.label = Label(self.master, text = name)`.

Comment: What exactly are you referring to when you say "assign the class to new window"?! `Menu(self.menu)` does not "assign the class to new window"; it instantiates the class *and passes a variable (`self.menu`) to its `__init__` method.* – Perhaps read up some more on Python OOP basics?

Comment: I see now the problem. self.entry.get() needs to be in method so it calls the name, but cheers for telling me how to pass it initially. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Menu, needs a method to set the name. e.g.:

```
class myMenu:
    def __init__(self,...):
        ....

    def set_Me(self,some_name):
        self.some_name = some_name
        # or
        self.label.setName(some_name)
```

in the main program you call:

```
self.app.set_Me(self.name)
```

The above is pseudo code. But you should get the idea.
This technique you can use to pass variables to any class at any time.

If you need to pass variable only once:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self,my_variable):
        self.my_variable = my_variable
```

Comment: Way overcomplicating it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 : make a better proposal. We all are here to learn

Comment: The better proposal is in the comments.

Comment: Some questions are not worth answering (and most aren't worth answering incorrectly).

Comment: Not all of us are experts. I know well how difficult it was to get started. So this is why I even answer stupid questions if I see that someone is stuck somewhere. Here at least we have see that Max put some code in his question. So he is really trying...